# How do i export color assets from Adobe Xd?

Tags: adobe-xd

I've been working on a UI recently in AdobeXD and when I finished everything up and was ready to export to flutter, one annoying thing happened when I was testing. I had the unpleasant surprise to discover that my background color was missing! I figured out that I didn't select `export color assets`. Unfortunately, this did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

install advanced Export plugin

or use Share Tab in Adobe XD 2020

Answer (score 0):

Using the Share tab in XD, select the "Development" view setting and provide (or open) the link in a browser. From there, you will be prompted to view in "Specs" mode (or click the small developer icon in the upper right of your browser) to view a panel with the colors.

As you hover over the tiles, you can click to copy the hex code.
[(screen capture from colors in browser showing hover value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgOAy.jpg)